# Сколько файловых дескрипторов доступно в Unix? Как обойти ограничение в 16384 в Windows 7?

Tags: сеть, сокет, backend, connection

Тестировал в Windows 7, там доступно максимально 16384 файловых дескриптора. Соответственно, удержать более ~16300 сокет-соединений не представляется возможным с одного компьютера.

Получается, что доступно 65536 портов, и каждый может адресовать 65536 подключений, в итоге ~ 4.3 миллиарда клиентов, в теории.

Возможно ли выжать из одного компа и одной сетевой карты столько подключений, если не брать в расчёт расход оперативной памяти на это?

Скажите, кто знает точный ответ, как с этим обстоят дела на Unix-системах? Как вообще решаются эти вопросы в продакшене - только горизонтальным масштабированием, или есть способ заставить работать один компьютер для этих целей?

Comment: Обычно лимит файловых дескрипторов на один процесс распространяется. Никто не мешает создать несколько процессов, которые будут слушать один и тот же порт. Собственно так обычно и делается.

Comment: И 4.3 миллиарда клиентов одной машине все равно крайне сложно выдержать. 10 ГБит порты максимум передают 14 млн пакетов в секунду. Значит при 4.3 миллиарда клиентов каждому клиенту один пакет можно будет отправлять не чаще, чем раз в 5 минут

Comment: "Никто не мешает создать несколько процессов, которые будут слушать один и тот же порт" - если порт занят, то слушать его не получится с другого процесса.

"Обычно лимит файловых дескрипторов на один процесс распространяется" - я тестировал, на любое количество процессов один общий лимит в 16384 дескриптора.

Если вы пишете про то, как в Unix происходит, то уточните этот момент, плиз.

Comment: Да, по WiKi, общий размер кадра Ethernet, содержащего IP-пакет с пустым сегментом TCP - 24 + 20 + 20 = 64 байта, а это ~ 15 миллионов пакетов/сообщений. Но я не говорю о количестве передаваемых данных в секунду, у меня только вопрос про удержание открытых соединений.

Comment: А в чем сама задача? запустить по максимуму? понять, почему созданный сервер не может подключить больше пользователей? или просто интересно?

Comment: Мне надо знать, какие ресурсы готовить под нагрузку: или ОЗУ повышать, или количество нод.

Comment: @Sergei Вы открываете порт на прослушивание в главном процессе, после чего выполняете fork(), все дочерние процессы наследуют этот дескриптор и могут параллельно выполнять на нем accept. Кроме того в unix системах возможна пересылка открытого дескриптора сокета в другой процесс через unix-domain socket

Comment: Кроме того в linux сейчас есть более крутой вызов clone() который позволяет при запуске нового процесса управлять тем, какие ресурсы у потомка будут свои, а какие разделяемые. И по факту вы можете создать например thread, полностью разделяющий память с основным процессом, но при этом имеющий свое пространство файловых дескрипторов (разумеется с наследованием уже открытых)

Comment: И странно, но в интернете пишут что в windows 16 млн файловых десрипторов. но лимиты конечно надо руками менять на процесс. И да, я писал в основном про unix системы, где отдельные ограничения на процесс и есть конечно общесистемные, но их после тюнинга хватает

Comment: И кстати, если вам нужно удерживать столько соединений, то стоит задуматься о переходе на UDP

Comment: @Mike, вы указали на возможность передачи указателя между процессами на открытый слушатель порта - в рамках кодинга на Golang, я хз, как это сделать, учитывая, что открытие слушателя является блокирующей операцией без контроля мьютекса к указателю, и мне не понятна целесообразность этого действия, так как порт позволяет удержать 64К виртуальных подключений, но я хочу преодолеть порог в 16К, для начала, а мой вопрос состоит в том, чтобы узнать от опытных Unix-кодеров, сколько файловых дескрипторов ОС Unix позволяет держать открытыми на момент, имеет ли смысл переносить сервер с W7 на Unix?

Comment: Как вариант, попробуйте создать клиент и сервер со счётчиком открытых сокетов на удобном для Вас языке, и задайте 100 000 подключений в цикле. Утыкание в порог 16384 покажет наглядно мою проблему, сервер перестаёт принимать новых клиентов, а клиенты будут висеть в очереди.

Comment: На уровне ОС (и windows и unix) открытие слушателя и собственно прослушивание - это разные действия и между ними процесс может размножаться с наследованием при этом дескриптора. Как в golang не знаю. Возможно это стоит указывать в вопросе, так как это может оказаться ограничением языка.

Comment: Замечу, что на linux системе, которая у меня сейчас под рукой стоит максимум 6815744 файловых дескрипторов на систему и 1024 на процесс. но это все настраивается.

Comment: @Mike, можно ли считать ответом на мой вопрос тот факт, что количество дескрипторов зависит от предварительных настроек системы? Цифры уже есть, уже понятнее становится.

Comment: похоже Вы хотите что бы мы тут решили для Вас задачу, которая известна только Вам. На одной машине люди умудряются держать до 2 миллионов соединений. я держал работающими около 50к-60к (такой себе особый чатик), но девопсы чуточку тюнинговали систему.

Comment: Для доказательства общего пула дескрипторов внутри ОС, приведу такой пример:

1000 открытых картинок/документов уменьшает лимит до 15384.

Comment: @KoVadim, меня интересует только одно число - количество доступных одновременно дескрипторов открытых файлов в ОС Unix. Я не просил решить какую-то задачу. Это число даст мне понимание того, переходить ли на Unix, тратить ли время на исследования.

Comment: в windows по умолчанию да, 16к дескрипторов. В линуксе по умолчанию 1024 (ulimit -n), но легко можно сделать миллион (я делал, это работает).

Comment: @KoVadim, Mike, спасибо, ребята! Начинаю копать в направлении Unix!